# Show MainMenu.xib from other Window

Tags: xcode, macos, xib, viewcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I have set the first viewController in my xcode project to a different view controller.
However I want to open the MainMenu.xib from within my first view controller.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

Thanks for any help!

Best,
Julian

Comment: And this is OSX, not iOS, right?

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot to mention.